# TypeError when using re.findall

Tags: python, regex, ipv4

I'm trying to extract IP addresses from an XML document, here's the relevant code.

```
def traverseNode(node):
    output = node.find(****)
    if output is not None:
        ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', output)
        for ip in ips:
            print ip
    for child in node.getchildren():
        traverseNode(child)
```

This code returns the error TypeError: expected string or buffer
Any ideas on what's causing this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the type of `output`?  I would typically guess that it is another `node` or something and not a string or buffer ...

Comment: `find` returns the node object. You'll probably want to search for IP in `output.text` or `output.attrib` or something like that

Comment: Yeah, turns out I needed to set output to nod.find().text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the second arg to re.findall(pattern,arg) is a string. You can use str(arg) to make sure you putting string in re.findall.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to change the line to:
    output = node.find('****').text

Comment: IMO that is error prone in the sense that if match is not found, it will throw an `AttributeError: NoneType object has not attribute text`. Continue doing it as you were, but when using `re` do `ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', output.text)`